# how to scroll through quick doc in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, shortcut

I have managed to get the `quick doc` to show up on Android Studio on mouse move (`Android Studio > Editor > General`). But now each time I try to scroll through the doc that shows up, the doc disappears. How do I get the doc to stay put so I can scroll through it?